# Stop radio button from changing, show popup, then change radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dom

What I am trying to do is to prevent the user from changing the radio button until they confirm that they want to leave the "page". The radio button should not change to the one they clicked until after they click on the button in the popup to say "ok leave page".

This call handles changing the page to the selected radio button, and everything else. This should only be fired if the button in the popup is clicked:

```
$("body").on("change", "input[type='radio'][name='quote-type']:checked", function(e){

//Change the radio button and everything else

});
```

This handles the popup and everything:

```
  $(function(){
    var LEAVEPAGE;
    //Radio button changes, so show a popup
    $("body").on("change", ".coverage-options-wrapper li:not(.custom) input[type='radio'][name='quote-type']", function(e){

         e.preventDefault();
         e.stopPropagation();
         LEAVEPAGE = e.currentTarget;

         //Show the popup to ask if you are sure you want to switch radio buttons

         });
    //Click the button in the popup to leave the page, so change the originally clicked radio button.
    $("body").unbind("click").on("click", ".leave-page", function(){

        $(LEAVEPAGE).prop("checked", true).trigger("change"); //triggers change for the first call to be run, to actually change the page

    });
});
```

What is happening is the radio button is just being changed regardless, it shows the popup too, however it isn't waiting for a response from the popup. It just switches anyways. Also, when I click on the `.leave-page` button, it triggers change (it's suppose to be so that it will load the new page attributed to that button), however it ALSO triggers the popup again (as they both use the change event).

I am very stumped.

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Answer (score 2):

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/ehLZ2/)

**JS**

```
var optionTarget;

$(":radio").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   optionTarget = e.target;
   $("#leave-dialog").show(); 
});

$("#leave-dialog button").click(function(){
   $("#leave-dialog").hide();
});

$("#leave-btn").click(function(){
    $(optionTarget).prop('checked', true);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" name="bleh" value="yes" checked>option 1
<input type="radio" name="bleh" value="no">option 2
<div id="leave-dialog">Are you sure?
    <br/>
    <button id="leave-btn">Yes</button>
    <button>No</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I had used this before, however in Chrome and IE it seemed not to work, it still had the bug. I am trying to test it now, but the application isn't working right now.

Comment: Ok so yea, doing this isn't working for me in Chrome.. It doesn't switch the radio button, however it is not stopping the "change" event from being fired on the fields. I need the change event not to fire in the first part..

Comment: Hmmm, the fiddle demo works for me in Chrome. As the comments above have stated, would you mind creating a fiddle, or at least showing a demo site? We don't know what your HTML looks like, or what other script is in effect that might cause stuff to not work.

Comment: Oddly the demo does work fine, and even my demo I created works.. http://jsfiddle.net/D2vvc/

But what is happening on the site is the change event is being fired.. for whatever reason it's not in my demo...